# get_object_taxonomies() returns empty array for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, custom-taxonomy

I just want to know why `get_object_taxonomies('custom-post-type-name')` return empty array for custom post types but works fine with post as argument : `get_object_taxonomies('post')` and returns:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'category' (length=8)
  1 => string 'post_tag' (length=8)
  2 => string 'post_format' (length=11)
```

Comment: Are you sure the problem is not a simple typo?

Comment: Where are you using this code? Perhaps you're outside of the Loop so there is no object it's running on?

Comment: @JackJohansson I found the cause of this issue : the problem is that the post types isn't recognizable inside my plugin folder :/any idea ?

Comment: @WebElaine : the problem is that the post types isn't recognizable inside my plugin folder

Comment: As you mentioned the function works fine with an argument - have you tried passing one of the CPTs as an argument to see if that works? Hard to help without further context about where and how this code is running.

Answer (score 1):

I have run into the same issue. I believe the root cause is the order of execution. For the sake of experiment, I ran `get_object_taxonomies()` immediately after `register_taxonomy()`, in fact in the same function and it worked as expected. So what to do? Use `add_action()` hook to execute `get_object_taxonomies()` *after* `register_taxonomy()`. The correct order of execution can be guaranteed via 3rd argument of `add_action( ... int $priority = 10 ... )`